# Can Elements contain Blocks in bem

Tags: html, css, oocss, bem

I have been told I was wrong for writing the code like I have below. I suppose elements can not contain blocks and its bad b.e.m.

```
<ul class="b-nav">

    <li class="b-nav__item">

         <a href="#" class="b-nav__item__link"> Item </a>


     </li>

 </ul>
```

I thought about writing it this way but it doesn't show the hierarchy as well.

```
<ul class="b-nav">

    <li class="b-nav__item">

         <a href="#" class="b-nav__link"> Item </a>


     </li>

 </ul>
```

Here is another way but to me it seems worse than the example above.

```
<ul class="b-nav">

    <li class="b-nav__item">

         <a href="#" class="b-link"> Item </a>


     </li>

 </ul>
```

Is the way I originally coded it wrong? If so why, and what is the best alternative.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two first samples? And, are you just asking about class names?

Comment: I cannot see a difference or a mistake in what you did.

Comment: @EricHarms What's wrong is using BEM for most of real-world websites. It's typically better to utilize core CSS features such as child selector. So your HTML should actually be like this: `<ul class="nav"><li><a href="#">Item</a></li></ul>`, and your CSS selectors should be like `UL.nav > LI`, `UL.nav A`, or `UL.nav > LI > A`.

Comment: @xec: After having read the introduction to BEM here:http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/ I believe that he is indeed talking about the naming convention for his classes.

Comment: what's your problem? `<ul class="b-nav"><li class="b-nav__item"><a href="#" class="b-nav__link"> Item </a></li></ul>` it's OK!

Comment: I do that for improved performance with how selector engines read rules. It also allows me to use that class on non list tags such as div or dl (location independence). The main question is can a element contain a element as shown in the first example.

Comment: I did make a correction to the code Nikos - sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

You should use second or third samples.

Or you could use this one (it uses BEM mixes; we have a [talk](http://clubs.ya.ru/yasubbotnik/replies.xml?item_no=682) on this in Russian). It is helpful then you need to access `link` elem of `b-nav` from javascript code.

```
<ul class="b-nav">

    <li class="b-nav__item">

         <a href="#" class="b-nav__link b-link"> Item </a>

     </li>

 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think naming it nav_*link is more accepted than nav*_item__link, even if a link belongs to an item. Maybe what I was doing was overkill to show that hierarchy. In the end, both belong to the same block.

I saw some examples in the comments of each link  below

https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css/issues/155

http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

"Using elements within elements is not recommended by the BEM methodology." - that's it, nothing more, nothing less.

Concerning the basic naming structure, [Smashing Mag](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/) has a great tree figure displaying how this should be done:

```
<b:page>
  <b:head>
    <b:menu>
      ...
    </b:menu>
    <e:column>
      <b:logo/>
    </e:column>
    <e:column>
      <b:search>
        <e:input/>
        <e:button>Search</e:button>
      </b:search>
    </e:column>
    <e:column>
      <b:auth>
        ...
      </b:auth>
    <e:column>
  </b:head>
</b:page>
```

Which is nicely transformable in the follwoing JSON format:

```
    {
  block: 'page',
  content: {
    block: 'head',
    content: [
      { block: 'menu', content: ... },
      {
        elem: 'column',
        content: { block: 'logo' }
      },
      {
        elem: 'column',
        content: [
          {
            block: 'search',
            content: [
              { elem: 'input' },
              {
                elem: 'button',
                content: 'Search'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        elem: 'column',
        content: {
          block: 'auth',
          content: ...
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Personally I would recommend to use your second version - in the third the relation/dependence between the ul and a tags is not represented in the class naming.
Well, probably you've already solved this in the past 2 years, but maybe someone similarly lost in the right BEM syntax will find this answer useful...